# WCF http services blocked by windows 10 firewall

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-firewall

I have 3 self hosted WCF windows services communicating with each other over http port 80 using basic http binding. On the same machine I have a website (also running on default port 80) hosted in IIS which also manages and communicates with one of those services. Everything works fine within this windows 10 hosting machine i.e. the website can talk to the services and the services can talk to each other.

When I try to access the website from another PC on the network I get a message in the browser saying 'server DNS address could not be found'. I can't even access the WCF service metadata url.

This looks like a firewall issue on the host machine so I added inbound and outbound rules for TCP port 80 and made sure the rules 'World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)' and 'World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)' are enabled. None of these changes worked so I removed the TCP rules I added.

Finally I disabled the firewall completely and I was able to access the website from another PC. However, when I re-enabled the firewall, the website continued to work and all of a sudden my WCF metadata is also accessible! 
I don't understand why this is happening. I have successfully recreated the problem several times.

Can anyone offer an explanation or suggest any other firewall rules to try?

My end goal is to package up the services and website into an installer so I don't want my end users to have to mess around with the firewall. They may not even be able to turn it off and on again.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about outbound rules on port 80 for http?

Comment: Already tried this. Adding inbound and outbound rules for TCP 80 also affects http.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The url I was using to access the hosting machine used the machines name. In order for the machine to respond to a name lookup was to enable the firewall rule called 'Network Discovery (NB-Name-In)' for the public profile. This rule allows traffic on UDP port 137. Once the name lookup has been cached the url will be properly routed. This explains why it worked after I disabled then enabled the firewall again.